# Query ajax with parameter only works in IE when the IE debugger is open

Tags: jquery, ajax, debugging, internet-explorer

I just created an Ajax method.
It works if I don't pass any data to the controller.
If I want to pass some data to the controller.
It works only if I open the IE degguer.
I tried to add the cache option to false.
But it does not work.
Here is some of my code :

```
function ReportIdLoad(reportId) {
   $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        url: 'WebReportGeneratorView.aspx/ReportIdLoad',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(reportId),
        dataType: 'json'
    })
}

[WebMethod]
public static void ReloadReportWorkbookContext(string reportId)
{
   //My code
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Wrap it in try/catch and call 'alert(error)'. What error text you get?

Comment: Sounds like a race effect. You are probably expecting asynchronously delivered data to behave as if it were synchronous.

Comment: I have no mistake catch by the catch error :(

Comment: I specify that my function is triggered by the window.onbeforeunload event.
I want to do server side actions when my page closes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Roamer-1888 :

Thanks for the track.

Indeed,
It sounds like this problem.

I add the option :

```
async: false
```

And I get to my break point.

Comment: Ludovic, that proves the point but isn't a great solution. You should really omit `async:false`, return a promise from ` ReportIdLoad()`, and chain `ReportIdLoad(...).then(...)` wherever it is called.

Comment: You might like to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call). There's plenty to take on board but it will be a good investment.

Comment: I think I don't need the then.
Because I don't expect a return coming from the Ajax query.
The controller does a processing without needing to return something to the ajax function.
no ?
(This is my full comment sorry enter keyboard error)

Comment: But there must be something which is dependent on the ajax completing. Otherwise there wouldn't have been a problem in the first place, and `async:false` wouldn't have had any affect.

Comment: Would not it come from the fact that I call my method in a window.onbeforeunload? 

And that the window closes before the end of the Ajax query and that it is lost? 

    `window.onbeforeunload = function (event) { 
         var reportId = { "reportId": $("#HiddenReportId").val() }; 
         ReportIdLoad(reportId); 
    };`

Comment: Used that way, you have "fire-and-forget" ajax. There's no attempt to wait for the ajax response before the page unloads, therefore nothing to inhibit the page unloading if the ajax should fail, and no opportunity to warn the user. I'm not sure that's something I would ever do.